# Ember invoke a component function from another component in same engine parent

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

my requirement is to use component actions from another component.Need to know whether it is possible to use data-down for this case.

Say,

I'm trying to invoke first-component from here **engine/addon/templates/application.hbs**
like below

> > engine/addon/templates/application.hbs

```
    {{#if invokeFirstCompo}}
    <FirstComponent action={{'actionFromSecondCompo'}}/>
    {{/if}}
```

From this **FirstComponent**  i want to invoke, second-component function handled in

> > engine/addon/components/SecondComponent.js

```
actionFromSecondCompo(){
 console.log("Print Invoked secondcomponent");
}

Note: Both components are in same engine parent
i've tried to use **extend** the firstComponent in secomdCompo js like below.

>>engine/addon/components/SecondComponent.js
```

import FirstComponent from 'engine/components/FirstComponent';
export default FirstComponent.extend({

```
But issue here is, its invoking willDestroyElement() function from FirstComponent.Hence i don't need the changes handled inside this destroy function.
```

Comment: can you fix the formatting of this post?
I'm not sure what is supposed to be code and what is text

Answer (score 0):

Relevant documentation is here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/component-arguments-and-html-attributes/

But, the way to pass actions is via *direct reference*.

For example:

```
// SecondComponent
export default class extends Component {
  someAction = () => {}
}
```

```
{{! second component's template }}
<SomeOtherComponent @foo={{this.someAction}} />
```

Note that *arguments* are prefixed with `@`, and functions on a class are referenced via `this.`